# how to avoid index out of bound exception when displaying the whole data

Tags: java, oop, exception

```
//test class

public class Test {
public static ArrayList<sports> listofsports;
    public static ArrayList<group> listofGroups;
    private static Object IOException;
```

i have added 10 groups to the listofGroups arraylist
and 3 sports to the listofsports arraylist

// displaying the whole data

```
public  static void displaywholedata() {
 
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < listofGroups.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listofsports.size(); j++) {

            System.out.println(listofsports.get(i).getSportsplayed() + " " + listofsports.get(i).getListofgroups().get(j).getThenamegroup() + " ");
        } 

    } 


displaywholedata(); }
```

the error that is giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at Test.displaywholedata(Test.java:52)
    at Test.main(Test.java:139)
Command execution failed.
```

can someone help me detect where is the problem in my code

Comment: How do you know `listofGroups` and `listofsports` are the same size ? You check `i` against `listofGroups` then use it to index into `listofsports`. - actually on second thoughts looks like you have `i` and `j` reversed :-)

Comment: Please provide the definition of sports and group

Comment: Your `Test` class may not even have this `listofsports.get(i).getListofgroups().get(j)` structure.

Comment: getlistofgroups is a getter for the list of groups in the sports class

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < listofGroups.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < listofsports.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(listofsports.get(i).getSportsplayed() + " " + listofsports.get(i).getListofgroups().get(j).getThenamegroup() + " ");
    }
```

`i` is 0 to `listofGroups.size()` but then you use `i` to access `listofsports`

`j` is 0 to `listofsports.size()` but then you use `j` to access `listOfGroups`

you have i and j swapped. Either swap all the is and js in the println of swap the is and js in the for loops. Convention dictates the for loops are right so change the println.

Comment: i tried swapping in the println but the error still exists

Comment: Then you need to split ypur println over 3 lines to see which `get()` is failing - did you change all 3 ?